# Linear transformation defined by an $m$ by $n$ matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I came across these terms on an MIT open course on youtube:

> An $m\times n$ matrix defines a linear transformation from the $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector
>   space to $\mathbb{R}^m$ vector space.

Can someone please explain in simple terms what this means?
Why not a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space?

Comment: What do you get if you multiply an $m\times n$ matrix with an $n\times 1$ matrix?

Comment: An $m$ x $1$ matrix? I am still struggling to see the connection sorry.

Comment: Exactly. Thus if you call your $m\times n$ matrix $A$, then $A: \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$ defined by $A(v) = A\cdot v$ is a linear transformation (you can check easily).

Comment: So what is v and what is A(v) ? and how do I check for linear transformation.

Comment: You should say a few words about your background and level of math education. Otherwise I fear that people will assume way to much knowledge on your side.

Comment: Shamefully I have a Bachelor's in an engineering course - but I was never an attentive students in my classes, mathematics or otherwise.

Comment: Does the answer below answer your question?

Comment: @MaikPickl : No it does not, could you please have a look at the comments below the answer so maybe I can understand better what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain it as simple as I can. First of all you need to recognize that a $m\times n $ matrix $A$ gives you a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. This is by taking a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and "multiplying" it in the following way:

$$ A(x)=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
a_{m1} &\ldots & a_{mn}  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^n x_ia_{1i}\\\vdots\\\sum_{i=1}^n x_ia_{mi} \end{pmatrix}. $$

The word "linear" comes from the relation $A(x+y)=A(x)+A(y)$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A(\lambda x)=\lambda A(x)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (You should check this!). What does this mean? Linearity basically means that the map $A$ from   $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ transforms linear spaces into linear spaces. You can see this for example in the rule $A(\lambda x)=\lambda A(x)$. You can interpret this as following: The map $A$ sends a multiple of a vector to a multiple of it's image vector.

Comment: Hey I did check what Linear transformation exactly meant, and that is not where I am confused.

Comment: So basically what I understand is - When I say that the matrix A gives us  map from $R^n$ to $R^m$, it means that an n x 1 vector when multiplied by A(Left multiplication) gives me a m x 1 vector.

Comment: A $n\times 1$ vector is a strange way of writing it, but yes this is what you get.

Comment: So this is what was confusing right, the statement " An $m\times n$ matrix defines a linear transformation from the $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector
 space to $\mathbb{R}^m$ vector space." mentions nothing about multplication with vector spaces - it is assumed to be understood!

Comment: Since I don't know your source I can not really comment on this. Maybe they have allready defined the multiplication in an earlier lecture that you missed or something like this.

Comment: Maybe, but thanks a ton for clarifying this up!(PS: This is all that it means right?)

Comment: In principle yes. This concept is really really usefull in a lot of areas because it is so simple.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a map using a matrix, the elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are usually considered to be column vectors (that is, $n \times 1$ matrices). Under this convention, a matrix $A \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ defines a linear map $L_A \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ by **left multiplication** so $L_A(x) := Ax$. This is defined when $x$ is a column vector and results in a $m \times 1$ column vector.

If one would work with row vectors and **right multiplication** (this can be seen sometimes in old textbooks) then a matrix $A \in M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{R})$ would define a map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ by $R_A(x) := xA$. This convention is more intuitive in the sense that it defines a linear map between the spaces "in the natural" order but it has other drawbacks that make it less useful. For example, when constructing a matrix that corresponds to a linear system of equations, you would have to convert the equations into columns instead of rows in order to identify the solution space with the kernel of the associated linear map.

Comment: Sorry but could you please tell me what is $L_A (x)$?

Comment: Basically what I want to ask is : How is the matrix defining the linear transformation and not the act of multiplying it by x which defines a transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$

Comment: Given a matrix $A$, I denoted the linear transformation that $A$ defines by $L_A$ (here, $L$ is for "left" and I chose the name $L_A$ because $A$ multiplies the vector from the left) and it is defined by $L_A(x) := Ax$ (so $L_A$ sends a vector $x$ to the vector $Ax$ which is obtained by multiplying $x$ by $A$).

Answer (score 1):

> A **linear transformation** is any function $L \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ that satisfies two properties:
>
> - $L(x + y) = L(x) + L(y)$ for all $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$; and
> - $L(cx) = c\,L(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and all real numbers $c$.

Meanwhile, an $m \times n$ **matrix** is just an $m \times n$ array of numbers.

**Question:** In what way does an $m \times n$ matrix (array of numbers) give rise to a linear transformation (a function satisfying those two properties)?

This was answered in complete generality by other users.  So, let me instead answer your question with an example.

**Example:** Suppose $A$ is the $2 \times 3$ matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}.$$
From $A$, we can define a function $L \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:
$$L(x,y,z) = A \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x + 2y + 3z \\ 4x + 5y + 6z \end{pmatrix}.$$
Since $A$ has $3$ columns, the input of $L$ has to be a vector $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Since $A$ has $2$ rows, the output of $L$ has to be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Hopefully this example illustrates the idea.

You can check that the function $L$ defined in this way is, in fact, a linear transformation, meaning that the two properties described above hold.

Comment: You made a mistake with number of rows and columns of A

Comment: @novice: fixed now.  sorry about that.